# Yii2 вставляется пустая строка в бд

Tags: yii2

Изучаю Yii2, и думаю проблема очевидная, но не для меня.
При сохранении данных через форму, в бд заноситься пустая строка.
Использовал как **QueryBuilder** так и **ActiveRecord**. Удалял валидацию из модели, не помогло.
Информации, как ни странно вообще ноль на просторах снг.
Кроме оф. документации,и ее переводов, вообще ничего. Кучу видео пересмотрел, но кроме повторения одного и того же, ничего нового не узнал.
Костыли городить не хочу, и абы как туда всунуть инфу не тот путь.
Использовал стандартный виджет у видах:

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Имя') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->label('Категория') ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Модель

```
            namespace app\models;

            use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

            class Products extends ActiveRecord
            {

                public $name;
                public $category;


                    public static function tableName()
                    {
                        return 'products';
                    }

            }
```

Контролер в нужном методе:

```
     $model = new Products();
     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
         $model->save();
```

Без валидации, без проверок, просто сохранение в случае отправки формы постом.

P.S. Уже ненавижу этот фреймворк, через его документацию, хоть она и огромна, но детали не разъясняются. Потратил около недели на эту проблему...Помогите хоть идеями, возможно проблема напрямую не состоит во фреймворке.

Comment: Почитайте про сценарии и про безопасные атрибуты [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-models.md). У вас не загружается модель, так как у вас нет безопасных атрибутов в силу того, что вы убрали правила валидации.

Comment: Вы точно посылаете во View $model?

Comment: Скиньте полный код action и мы решим вашу проблему. Вы 100% забыли послать $model во View поэтому и такая проблема

Comment: @RomanGrinyov безопасные атрибуты(safe) назначаются по умолчанию. Они не причем.

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, почему это? ... `Массовое присвоение применяется только к так называемым безопасным атрибутам, которые являются атрибутами, перечисленными в scenarios()` -> `По умолчанию scenarios() будет возвращать все сценарии и атрибуты найденные в rules()` -> автор говорит, что затёр `rules()` -> следовательно -> безопасных атрибутов нет, так как нет `rules()` -> следовательно -> по дефолту атрибуты будут `null`, при том, что `load()` будет срабатывать (но в холостую) -> следовательно -> именно поэтому сохраняется модель с путыми атрибутами (так как они все равны `null`).

Comment: By default, an active attribute is considered safe and can be massively assigned. --- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, отдуда же: `An active attribute is one that is subject to validation in the current scenario.` Сценария у нас нет, то есть он есть (`default`), но это пустой массив, так как нет `rules()` — то есть атрибутов нет, поэтому и не работает массовое присвоение. А `null`ы назначает сам PHP, так как по умолчанию значение свойства равно `null`.

Comment: Ждем автора. Проблема не в сценарии, а в том, что он не послал $model в представление. Вероятность = 99%

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41813/discussion-between-roman-grinyov-and-urmuz-tagizade).

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade Извиняюсь что не написал этого, но модель я послал =\  

`return $this->render('index', ['model'=> $model]);`

Тоесть, есть возможность того что проблема кроется в валидации? Можете подсказать способ отключения ее, задав параметрами, ибо по другому вижу не получиться). 

И еще одно, когда напрямую задаю например 
`$model->name = 'Dima';`
`$model->save();`
, то это значение вставляется в поле инпута...

Если генерировать CRUD через Gii, все равно не получается обновлять, или вставлять. Взять могу з базы - обратное нет.. Но все равно вам благодарен, спасибо за мысли

Comment: Если генерируете через Gii, то также вставляются пустые значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Gii я указал ту самую модель, то есть продублировал. И как раз корень зла был в ней.`public $name` и `public $category` без значений, то есть они равны были `NULL`. Не знаю почему Yii  не перезаписал данные при `$model->save` (но догадываюсь — тут нужно что-то знать о атрибутах). Я удалил публичные свойства и код спокойно сработал, и с валидацией и без нее.
В модели у меня осталась только валидация и нужная табличка:

```
public function rules()
 {
 return [
      [['name'], 'required', 'message'=> 'Lorem ipsum'],
      [['category'], 'required', 'message'=> 'Bla bla bla']
        ];
 }

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'products';
}
```

В контролере, знаю что лучше через массовое присвоение, но это для себя, проверить на работоспособность.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new Products();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->name = Yii::$app->request->post('Products')['name'];
            $model->category = Yii::$app->request->post('Products')['category'];
            $model->save();

    }else{
            return $this->render('index', ['model'=> $model]);
    }
}
```

P.S. Можно вместо 
`$model->name = Yii::$app->request->post('Products')['name'];` написать   `$model->name;`  при сохранении, или не указывать вообще атрибуты. Пишу это, потому как видел много людей которые присваивают через Post.